# Put in CDetailView widget another widget

Tags: php, yii

I want to put into a row of the CDetailView widget a text which is displayed from another widget. How can i link those two?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    array( 
                'label'=>'TextHighlighter',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'this system.web.widgets.CTextHighlighter widget',
         ),
), ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend [CFormatter](http://yii.te.gd/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter), to create a custom class that will call [CTextHighlighter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTextHighlighter) widget and return the rendered value.

Than you would pass the formatter to the DetailView

```
$myCustomformat=new myFormat();
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'formatter'=>$myCustomformat,
'attributes'=>array(
    array( 
                'label'=>'Label',
                'type'=>'texthighligter',
                'value'=>'$model->data',
         ),
), ));
```

This would call the formatTexthighligter() method from your myFormat class, which returns the CTextHighlighter output.

Or read some other ways here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/